Styling the select input in WooCommerce checkout like the text inputs
URL to the checkout so you can see the source code:
https://whitebrightsmile.com/checkout/?add-to-cart=6627&quantity=1
The text inputs are given border-radius (through Elementor) and the border is actually a box-shadow to avoid layout shift when in focus because it increases by 1px (custom CSS):


.page-id-80 input[type=email], .page-id-80 input[type=text], .page-id-80 input[type=tel] {
    border: none;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(170, 170, 170, 0.3);
    }
    
.page-id-80 input[type=email]:focus, .page-id-80 input[type=text]:focus, .page-id-80 input[type=tel]:focus {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #FF6BA1;
}



Now I want the State select element to look exactly the same as the other form fields, with the "border" and the pink color when in focus.
It also appears that the select is a bit higher than the other fields, I want it to be the same height. It is not possible to style this select the same way as the other inputs, neither through Elementor or any CSS that I've figured out yet.
Can someone help me achieve this?

Add this css to your active theme style.css file
.elementor-80 .elementor-element.elementor-element-5d7cd29 .select2-container--default .select2-selection--single {
      height: auto;
      border: 1px solid #f5f5f5 !important;
}


Many thanks, had to change the color to #aaaaaa4d, but it almost fixed the heigt and made the "border" the same color. The input is a little off at the bottom compared to the fields on either side. https://imgur.com/a/KHTUk0l Is that because this one has an actual border, but the other two has box shadow? Also, how do I change the border color on focus without layour shift?
